# ¿Cómo cambio el tipo de dato de una columna solamente para hacer una consulta en MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta a una tabla para ver el máximo de los `id's` existentes, pero la columna de `id` es de tipo `varchar` por lo tanto ya que el `id` del ultimo registro sobrepasó el **99** entonces, me lo detecta como el máximo, entonces, mi idea era hacer que se cambie el tipo de dato de `varchar` a entero cuando haga la consulta para que así tome el último `id`, pero la verdad no sé y no tengo la más mínima menor idea de hacer, sí alguien me puede ayudar lo agradezco.

Dejo la consulta en `MySQL`

```
$select = "SELECT max(id_controlAsis) as id FROM control_asistencias";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes convertir el dato con CAST y luego buscar el valor máximo. Para un valor tipo `int` debes hacer el `cast` a tipo `unsigned`.

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id VARCHAR(11)
);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('1');
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('2');
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('100');
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES ('215');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT * FROM test;

| id  |
| --- |
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 100 |
| 215 |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT max(CAST(id AS UNSIGNED)) FROM test;

| max(CAST(id AS UNSIGNED)) |
| ------------------------- |
| 215                       |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Me funcionó, te lo agradezco mucho, eres la mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer, si quieres determinar el máximo en un campo **vachar**, tienes que ordenar de forma **DESC** el campo ** id_controlAsis  ** y aplicarle un **LIMIT 1** de esta manera obtienes el mayor valor de la columna y no tienes que cambiarla a entero, espero que te ayude. Gracias

**Aquí te dejo el ejemplo:**

```
$select = "SELECT id_controlAsis as id FROM control_asistencias ORDER BY id_controlAsis DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: No me funcionó seguía trayendome el mismo dato, pero igual, gracias